# Chromedriver crashes once running with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I have created Web test using Robotframework.
Once I am trying to run test with Jenkins, the test fails due to chromedriver crash on start. This is the message I receive:

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461585 (0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.4 x86_64)

Attempt to run it manually succeed, everything works fine.

This is a reduced code I am running:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Sanity Setup
    [Tags]    Sanity
    ${chrome_options} =     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    ${prefs}    Create Dictionary   credentials_enable_service=${false}
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-infobars
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --kiosk
    Create WebDriver    Chrome      chrome_options=${chrome_options}
Go to URL
    Go To  ${URL}


Finalize Tests
    close all browsers


*** Keywords ***
Provided precondition
Setup chromedriver
  Set Environment Variable  webdriver.chrome.driver  ./driver/chromedriver.exe
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I have to use headless browser, since I am running Jenkins on remote machine

Still investigating this way...

Comment: In order to help us we need to know a little more about your setup. Is Jenkins running on your own desktop as a PoC environment, or is it running on a server with a different OS (Linux, Windows etc)? In Jenkins are you running the test of a Slave node, or on the server itself? Can you also provide the exact command that Jenkins is using to start Robot Framework test and of course the one that you use to manually run the test?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Jenkins is running on Mac and job is executed on slave node. 

In both cases I am running the same command:
'robot sanity.robot'

Comment: The Slave Node is a Windows machine, and this script runs find on the slave node when being manually executed? Otherwise this: `Set Environment Variable  webdriver.chrome.driver  ./driver/chromedriver.exe` does not make sense in a Mac context.

Comment: Slave machine is Mac, please ignore the ".exe" it was added by mistake

Comment: Perhaps the chromedriver log file will shed some light on what is happening. Can you start chromedriver seperately on the slave node `chromedriver --port=9515 --log-path=c:\temp\webdriver.log` and then have jenkins run Robot with a testcase containing this statement `Open Browser  https://www.google.com    Chrome    remote_url=http://127.0.0.1:9515` and see what path is used to start chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate on what OS you are having Jenkins run this test? The code suggests your local machine is Windows, since you are setting the webdriver.chrome.driver to a Windows .exe? This will not work on Linux and Mac machines.

A manual for running Headless Chrome on Linux and Windows can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/5336747).

PS: [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) is coming to Linux and Mac very soon in Chrome 59, but it will take a little more time before Selenium and the Selenium-chrome-driver also support it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actually this is mistake since I am using Mac machine as a Jenkins slave (but it's running chromedriver anyway)